# Serilog Sink for Dynatrace, will this work if my machine is offline and send the rest logs once it gets online?

Tags: serilog, dynatrace

I have a WPF application, which has a lot of offline capabilities, Now we are in the discussion of if we should use Dynatrace for our log storage,
And If we do, will it cache the logs if offline and sync when it comes online?

I am using Serilog for logging.

I did not try it as We are still under discussion, if this is a capability or not?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.